# Alternative ways to load files from HDFS to hive when they are not in directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '${database_delimiter}'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '${database_location}/Person';
```

Here person is expected to be a directory. Whereas person is a part-m file and not a directory.

Comment: I have multiple files that are being stored using Multi Text Input Format. 
Ex: {database_location}/personA
 {database_location}/personB 
{database_location}/personC 
I'm trying to load this to hive with tables named 
personA 
personB 
personC

Comment: *Multi text output format

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, Hive will indeed fail to create a table over a file. It needs to be a directory location.

Therefore, whatever process you have needs to *make* said directory.

For example, whatever mapper process you have, you needed to specify an output *directory*, and if you failed to do that, then your files are placed in some location next to other files. (MapReduce should fail saying the destination directory already exists, though).

What you could do is move all part files into a new location

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p ${database_location}/Person/
$ # create hive table using that location
$ hdfs dfs -mv  ${database_location}/part-m* ${database_location}/Person/
$ # run hive query
```

Or, if you had raw files, you can do something similar

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p ${database_location}/Person/
$ # create hive table using that location
$ hdfs dfs -put somefile ${database_location}/Person/
$ # run hive query
```

Or use `LOCAL DATA INPATH` to read from one HDFS location to a Hive table